# Rewiring a house that has aluminum wiring

Tags: wiring, safety, aluminum

My house is at least partially wired with aluminum. I’m trying to replace what I can as I remodel. I can pull copper wire in some areas but can not pull out the aluminum easily as it is stapled down.

Is there a safe way to cap and tape the ends so I can leave the aluminum wire in the walls?

Comment: You can cap both ends, but AL wire was also used at the same time as multi branch circuits, two hots with a common neutral.  Just need to watch for house circuits with black, red and white wires.  They are on two breakers which could separated, so check that power is completely off when working in boxes.

Comment: If the aluminum cables are abandoned and not connected to the power, then I don't think you have to cap the ends, but you should ask the electrical inspector in your jusrisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminum isn't as dangerous as people think; it simply needs to be terminated properly on terminals rated for Aluminum wire, which 1970s era work was not.   It is also not immune to the problem of improper torque, in fact that was the other part of its "problem" - in the 70s, nobody realized screw torque was important on the small stuff, so nobody was torquing terminals.

However, if you have power wires in the wall you want to permanently abandon, you can simply cap them off at both ends.  I would gather all wires in that cable together into a single wire nut.

Wire nuts are not an appropriate connector for aluminum wire anyway. If the circuit were going to be energized, it would need to use Alumiconn connectors or the terminals on a CO-ALR rated device.